# Error in future_map() function of R while using in the remote cluster

Tags: r, cluster-computing, slurm, hpc

I am using university's cluster to perform some computations. The code I run:

```
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
plan(cluster, workers = cl)
selected_a <- future_map(dat, ~abess(as.matrix(.x[, names(X)]),
.x[, "errs"]), support.size = 10)
stopCluster(cl)
```

It returns the following error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
> what():  std::bad_alloc
> Erreur dans unserialize(node$con) :
> ClusterFuture () failed to receive results from cluster SOCKnode #1 (on ‘localhost’). The reason reported was ‘erreur de lecture de la connexion’. Post-mortem diagnostic: The total size of the 8 globals exported is 1.18 MiB. The three largest globals are ‘...furrr_chunk_args’ (605.80 KiB of class ‘list’), ‘X’ (581.48 KiB of class ‘numeric’) and ‘as.matrix’ (11.45 KiB of class ‘function’)

The code runs well in my local machine. Also, when I change 'future_map' to 'map' in the above code everything works perfectly both in my local machine and in the cluster. How could I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could potentially arise from requesting too few RAM compared with what R needs. Try increasing the amount of `--mem` or `--mem-per-cpu` in the job submission. It looks like the requested memory is sufficient for `map` but not for `future_map`.